# How to make minimum rectangle box using contours in scikit-image?

Tags: python, scikit-image

i have an image of rice grain's my objective is to find the length/width of rice grains and rotate them to 90 degree angle. So far I have gotten is that I have detected the rice grain by finding the contours using the function **measure.find_contours** in scikit-image. I have the contours now I want to find the length/width of the grain, draw rectangle around the grain and rotate it. Any insights on how to do it using scikit-image?

My code is:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os, skimage
from skimage import io, color, filters, morphology, measure, draw
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def Detect_Images():
    """Entering the directory name and join it with the current path"""
    directory = input('Enter directory: ')
    paths = os.getcwd() + '/' + directory
    image_name = []

    '''Detecting image names'''
    for path in Path(paths).rglob('*.jpg'):
        image_name.append(path.name)
    # print(image_name, paths)
    '''Reading images and converting them to Gray'''
    image_objects = []
    for file in image_name:
        image_objects.append(io.imread(str(paths) + '/' + str(file), as_gray=True))

    return image_name, image_objects


def Adaptive_Threshold(image_objects):
    """Applying adaptive thresholding"""
    thresholded_images = []
    for image in image_objects:
        blur = skimage.filters.gaussian(image)
        t = skimage.filters.threshold_otsu(blur)
        binary = blur > t
        arr = skimage.img_as_ubyte(binary)
        thresholded_images.append(arr)
    return thresholded_images


def Erosion(thresholded_images):
    """Performing erosion"""
    eroded_images = []
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    for image in thresholded_images:
        eroded_images.append(morphology.erosion(image, kernel))
    return eroded_images


if __name__ == '__main__':

    image_name, image_objects = Detect_Images()
    thresholded_images = Adaptive_Threshold(image_objects)
    eroded_images = Erosion(thresholded_images)

    '''Finding contours'''
    contours = []
    figs = []
    for image in eroded_images:
        contours.append(measure.find_contours(image, 0.8))
        # io.imshow(image)
        ss, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
        figs.append(ax)

    for i, j in zip(contours, image_name):
        print(j, ' has ', len(i), 'rice grains.')

    '''Drawing Contours'''
    for contour, fig in zip(contours, figs):
        a = fig
        for i in contour:
            a.plot(i[:, 1], i[:, 0], linewidth=2)
    plt.show()
```

And the image is:
[Rice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk96r.jpg)

Comment: Have you had a look at this [tutorial on the scikit-image website](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_regionprops.html)?

Comment: Why would i come here if i hadn't done my research beforehand ? Asked a question here after I had done my homework.

Comment: The second code snippet in that tutorial demonstrates how to find the width and length of elliptical contours, and then how to draw a box around them. That should be 3 out of your 4 questions answered. If for some reason the code in the tutorial doesn't address your problems, I would suggest to edit your question to show where it fails.